# Unable to run R Shiny in command line

Tags: r, shiny, command-line, r-markdown

I have trying to run Shiny from the command line but am unable to. I have created a demo shiny file the command I have tried to use and the error I get below:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r plot1}
ggplot(mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(
  data = filter(mpg, class == "subcompact"),
  se = FALSE
)
```
````

The command to run the script is:
`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::run('"D:/Test/testrmd.Rmd"', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))"` which is run from the command line

I get the error:

`Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'rmarkdown' Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart Execution halted`

Comment: do you have rmarkdown package installed? does not look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code file doesn't have any R shiny code, this is just an Rmarkdown file. Flexdashboard can use shiny, but doesn't have shiny by default. you need `runtime: shiny`(as well as the Rmarkdown package) to utilize the shiny functionality. Then for me, I opened my terminal to the directory where my .Rmd file was saved and ran what John and you suggested, but I am on Mac so it was a little different `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::run('delete.Rmd', shiny_args=list(launch.browser=TRUE))"`... which rendered the Rmd file and automatically launched the browser with the HTML file, awesome!

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
```

```{r plot1}
ggplot(mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(
  data = filter(mpg, class == "subcompact"),
  se = FALSE
)
```
````

[image]

Comment: This helps!

I actually realized that I also had to set the .libPaths in the environment variables for the command to work.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure rmarkdown package is installed. Then try this -

```
Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::run('"D:/Test/testrmd.Rmd"', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

If error perists, try `install.packages("rmarkdown")` and then run the above step

Comment: The Rmarkdown is installed

Comment: Works well, thanks! There seems to be an unclosed double quote in the original answer, though. The fixed version that did it for me was: `Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::run('./App/app.rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))"`.